# problems with a query elasticSearch and nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with a query ElasticSearch. I would like to find documents with respect to two values in a nested object and i should have this result:

```
{
    "took": 36,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 6.3647356,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "product2019",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "2561571",
                "_score": 6.3647356,
                "_source": {
                    "attribute": [
                        {
                            "value": "api gl2",
                            "type": "887",
                            "lang": "fr",
                            "country": "FR",
                            "numpro": "887"
                        }
                    ],
                    "idProduct": "2561571",
                    "type": "ARTICLE"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "product2019",
                "_type": "product",
                "_id": "2562471",
                "_score": 6.3647356,
                "_source": {
                    "attribute": [
                        {
                            "value": "api gl2",
                            "type": "887",
                            "lang": "fr",
                            "country": "FR",
                            "numpro": "887"
                        }
                    ],
                    "idProduct": "2562471",
                    "type": "ARTICLE"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But with my query i've not the good result. Here is my query:

```
{
    "size": 500,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
            "nested": {
                    "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                            "attribute.numpro": "887"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                            "attribute.value": "api gl2"
                            }
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                    },
                    "path": "attribute"
                }
            },
            "minimum_should_match": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

with this query the result = 0. Someone could explain to me why I do not have the right result?

and this my mapping:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "product":{
            "properties":{
                "type":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "idProduct":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "attribute":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "country":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "lang":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "type":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "value":{
                            "analyzer":"french",
                            "type":"string",
                            "fields":{
                                "value.lowercase":{
                                    "analyzer":"lowercase",
                                    "type":"string"
                                },
                                "value.notanalyzed":{
                                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                                    "type":"string"
                                },
                                "value.alphanumlower":{
                                    "analyzer":"alphanumlower",
                                    "type":"string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "numpro":{
                            "type":"long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking for exact match using term query. You need to use "attribute.value.notanalyzed"

And your mapping

````
"notanalyzed": 
{
   "type": "text",
   "index":"not_analyzed"
}
```

should be
````

"notanalyzed": 
{
   "type": "keyword"
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Elasticsearch 2.x syntax.

For multi-fields you don't have to repeat the field-name (e.g. instead of `"value.lowercase":` just use `"lowercase":`).

With this fix your mapping should look like this:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "product":{
            "properties":{
                "type":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "idProduct":{
                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                    "type":"string"
                },
                "attribute":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "country":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "lang":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "type":{
                            "index":"not_analyzed",
                            "type":"string"
                        },
                        "value":{
                            "analyzer":"french",
                            "type":"string",
                            "fields":{
                                "lowercase":{
                                    "analyzer":"lowercase",
                                    "type":"string"
                                },
                                "notanalyzed":{
                                    "index":"not_analyzed",
                                    "type":"string"
                                },
                                "alphanumlower":{
                                    "analyzer":"alphanumlower",
                                    "type":"string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "numpro":{
                            "type":"long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your query, you need to query against the not analyzed version of your multi-field:

```
{
    "term": {
        "attribute.value.notanalyzed": "api gl2"
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that in your hits you will still see all the attributes of the matching documents. If you want Elasticsearch to also return the specific attribute that caused the match you have to add `"inner_hits" : {}` to your nested query.

Unfortunately I cannot test the code, as I no longer have an Elasticsearch v2.x or v5.x at hand. Starting with Elasticsearch version 5, type `string` got replaced by types `text` (analyzed) and `keyword` (not analyzed). By default strings now get mapped to a multi-field, where `<field-name>` refers to the analyzed text-field and `<field-name>.keyword` refers to the not-analyzed keyword field. If you are on Elasticsearch version 5 you may want to consider using version 5 syntax, which will make your mappings easier.

For instance, this version 2 mapping:

```
"lang":{
    "index":"not_analyzed",
    "type":"string"
}
```

would look like this in version 5:

```
"lang":{
    "type":"keyword"
}
```

Let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: Please indicate whether the answer solved your "problem"